# VS Code crashes when I close windows PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio-code

I mostly open VS Code with "code." command from powershell. But today when I opened the VS Code and closed the Powershell VS Code also crashed:

[image: Powershell window]

Error Message:
(node:4628) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '\?\C:\Users\MuhammadQasim\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\spdlog\build\Release\spdlog.node'. This is deprecated, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.
(node:9792) Electron: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer: '\?\C:\Users\MuhammadQasim\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar.unpacked\spdlog\build\Release\spdlog.node'. This is deprecated, see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397.

Comment: The error message mentions the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18397). Have you looked inside?

Comment: Please post the error message as  text instead of as image.